# decode URL in ANT

Tags: java, url, ant, urldecode

I am developing an ANT build script that should be invoked via another application (the Oxygen XML editor). This application passes some properties, one of which is a path, encoded as an URL (note: I don't have control over this input; it just *is* an URL). For example, the property `${project.url}` is assigned `file:/F:/projectpath/`. In my ANT script, I'm stripping the `file:/` part to get a path I can use in ANT tasks like `<mkdir dir="${project.path}/_temp/>`.

Yet, this appears to be too simplistic for more complex URLs. Suppose the project path contains a space. Then the `${project.url}` property will be assigned `file:/F:/project%20path/`. Just stripping out the '`file:/` part results in a path that is still problematic to ANT tasks. In this case, the URL encoded space character (`%20`) should be decoded again to a space for the `<mkdir/>` task above to work.

Of course, this problem isn't limited to spaces, but applies to all characters that will end up escaped in the encoded URL. Therefore, the URL should be properly decoded in order to be of use in ANT tasks.

Is there an easy way in ANT (preferably without ANT-contrib) to:

1. decode a URL
2. assign this decoded URL to another property

...so that, given the property `${project.url}` with value `file:/F:/project%20path/`, I can derive another property `${project.path}` with value `F:/project path/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FoggyDay's excellent [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539454/396926) has set me on the right path to solve my problem. I've defined a `<scriptdef>` task that can be used to:

1. decode URLs to paths, and
2. store them in properties that can be used in the ANT file.

I can't program Java, so I've resorted to JavaScript and used its [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function. Since this task works as a counterpart of the [`<makeurl>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/makeurl.html) ANT task, I've named it 'makepath'.

Here's a working sample build file:

```
<project>
  <property name="project.url" value="file:/F:/project%20path"/>
  <scriptdef name="makepath" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="url"/>
    <attribute name="property"/>
    <![CDATA[
      var decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(attributes.get("url"));
      var path = decodedUrl.replace(/^[^:]+:\/+/g, "");
      self.project.setProperty( attributes.get("property"), path )
    ]]>
  </scriptdef>

  <makepath url="${project.url}" property="project.path"/>
  <echo>$project.path: ${project.path}</echo>

</project>
```

Of course this is just an illustrative example (otherwise there wouldn't be much point in explicitly declaring a URL if you need a path). But when you don't have control over the value of the `${project.url}` property (which in my case is passed via an external program), this seems a handy way to convert it to something useful for the ANT context.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a `<script>` task to set a variable, then use that variable later in your build.xml.

For example:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html

```
<script language="groovy">
  xmlfiles = new java.io.File(".").listFiles().findAll{ it =~ "\.xml$"}
  xmlfiles.sort().each { self.log(it.toString())}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess I could define a simple Javascript task `<script language="javascript"><![CDATA[decodeURIComponent(encodedURI)]]></script>`, but I don't see how I can integrate this as a kind of function that 1) escapes e.g. ${project.url} and 2) stores it in a separate property ${project.path} for later use. Sorry about my ignorance, I'm desperately hacking my way into ANT, but I don't see how the pieces of this puzzle fit.

Comment: Your suggestion pointed me towards a working solution, *many* thanks @FoggyDay!